# Removing HTTP and WWW from URL python

Tags: python, url

```
url1='www.google.com'
url2='http://www.google.com'
url3='http://google.com'
url4='www.google'
url5='http://www.google.com/images'
url6='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RB89BOxaYY
```

How to strip `http(s)` and `www`  from url in Python?

Comment: `"http://www.google.com/images"[11:]`

Comment: So What do you want as output?

Comment: elements after `?` are arguments (also called `query`) - uparse can keep it in separeted variables.

Comment: i want output without http(s) and www

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the string method [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
url = 'http://www.google.com/images'
url = url.replace("http://www.","")
```

or you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

url = re.compile(r"https?://(www\.)?")
url = url.sub('', 'http://www.google.com/images').strip().strip('/')
```

Comment: how if i also want to remove https?

Comment: NB: both of these replacements will remove occurrences of the substring anywhere they are found in the url, which might not be intended. Safer to explicitly specify that these substrings have to be found at the beginning of the url.

Answer (score 9):

A more elegant solution would be using urlparse:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def get_hostname(url, uri_type='both'):
    """Get the host name from the url"""
    parsed_uri = urlparse(url)
    if uri_type == 'both':
        return '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
    elif uri_type == 'netloc_only':
        return '{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
```

The first option includes `https` or `http`, depending on the link, and the second part `netloc` includes what you were looking for.

Comment: The question is about removing "http" ("https") **and** "www". Your code removes only a scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Could use regex, depending on how strict your data is. Are http and www always going to be there? Have you thought about https or w3 sites?

```
import re
new_url = re.sub('.*w\.', '', url, 1)
```

1 to not harm websites ending with a w.

edit after clarification

I'd do two steps:

```
if url.startswith('http'):
    url = re.sub(r'https?:\\', '', url)
if url.startswith('www.'):
    url = re.sub(r'www.', '', url)
```

Comment: http will always be there. www could be or  not.Sometime it could also be https?In that case how should i modify above code to remove https aslo

Comment: you mean like this  if url.startswith('http'): new_url = re.sub('.*w\.', '', url, 1)

Comment: it should be `'https?:\\'`

Answer (score -1):

This will replace when http/https exist and finally if www. exist:

```
url=url.replace('http://','')
url=url.replace('https://','')
url=url.replace('www.','')
```

Comment: This does triple the work necessary (compared to a regex) and would also replace occurrences of those substrings elsewhere in the url, which would not be intented.